# Oracle Query With Date Parameter Returns No Records on Date Column

Tags: oracle, date

I have the following code -

```
CMD = new OracleCommand("SELECT * FROM BOOKINGSV3 WHERE DT = :DateInQuestion ", Con);
CMD.Parameters.Add("DateInQuestion", OracleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Today;
```

DT is a Date column, I know Oracle stores dates explicitly and if I try manually with '14-AUG-17 00:00:00' I can retrieve the desired results. How can I search by a date using a parameter other than using a string parameter and constructing a string in the format '14-AUG-17 00:00:00'?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you were always looking for today then you could search on `trunc(sysdate)` instead of binding a value at all; but presumably that value will change?  Are the application and DB in the same locale? (Also maybe worth checking the stored dates are in the right century; can be a problem if your NLS_DATE_FORMAT uses YY instead of RR, but don't think that's the problem here...)

Comment: Yes the value will change, today is just an example. My dev machine uses the US keyboard layout the regional settings are UK (same as server). For Feb 2nd, I tried US and UK format parameters but still neither found any results - DateTime(2017, 8, 2) AND DateTime(2017, 2, 8)

Comment: OK, then if it's something about C# (or whatever this code is) I'm not going to spot it. But I'm still always suspicious of 2-digit years for this kind of thing, so if only to shut me up, can you check the `dt` values are actually 2017? And they are all set to midnight?

Comment: Yeah I've tried the following and can see them ok SELECT * FROM BOOKINGSV3 WHERE DT > TO_DATE('2017-08-13', 'YYYY-MM-DD')  but if again with SQL Developer, if I try SELECT * FROM BOOKINGSV3 WHERE DT = '14-AUG-17' I get nothing

Comment: That doesn't answer the 'midnight' question though, what times do the rows have? Also what is your NLS_DATE_FORMAT in SQL Developer?

Comment: @AlexPoole I did try SELECT * FROM BOOKINGSV3 WHERE DT > TO_DATE('2017-08-14 23:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and no results. Also SELECT * FROM BOOKINGSV3 WHERE DT = '14-AUG-17 00:00:00' gives " date format picture ends before converting entire input string"

Comment: What does `select to_char(dt, 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` give you? Dates in 2017, or 1917, or 0017? (And do you expect to have `dt` values in the future?)

Comment: Ah! This gives 2017-08-14 07:47:04 so perhaps DT has a time behind it after all

Answer (score 1):

If your `DT` values have non-midnight times then to get all values on a given day you can use a range:

```
SELECT * FROM BOOKINGSV3 WHERE DT >= :DateInQuestion AND DT < :DateInQuestion + 1
```

The `>=` means it will find times from midnight onwards; the `< .. + 1` will limit to before midnight on the following day.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to create a string containing the date you want to search and change your query to explicitly create a date using the date format you use in your string.

```
CMD = new OracleCommand("SELECT * FROM BOOKINGSV3 WHERE DT = to_date(':DateInQuestion','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ", Con);
```

This way you control the date format and not some NLS setting.

Comment: If it's being bound as a date (`OracleDbType.Date`), why would NLS settings matter anyway? (Also... using `MON` is still NLS-dependent; and if you've kept that because of the 14-AUG-17 value, then using YYYY will make that 0017 not 2017 *8-)